# Secondary IP not pingable from internet - Ubuntu 20.04 using netplan on Hetzner server

Tags: networking, docker-compose, ubuntu-20.04, hetzner, netplan

Let me start be saying I'm not an network expert. That being said, I'd need some help here as I'm breaking my head on this issue for two days now. I have several questions but will focus only on one specific one.

I ordered a hetzner root server and installed Ubuntu 20.04. Right after I ordered a secondary IP as I need it for my docker setup where I want two containers to be accessible directly on these two IP addresses? The IP addresses are both /32 public addresses assigned by Hetzner. My main ip address is accessible from internet, I can ping it from outside.

After requesting the second IP i received a mail from Hetzner that my orde was successful and I can configure my second IP. In the Hetzner docs I read that it should be as easy as adding the second ip address to the `addresses` portion in `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`. This file looks like this now:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp9s0:
      addresses:
        - 50.50.50.201/32
        - 50.50.50.199/32
      routes:
        - on-link: true
          to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 50.50.50.193
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - ...
```

Right after saving the file I ran `netplan try` which reported success and hit `enter` to save the new config. Running `ip addr` gives me:

```
...
2: enp9s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a8:a1:22:1f:22:82 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 50.50.50.201/32 scope global enp9s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 50.50.50.199/32 scope global enp9s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
...
```

Now I can ping the second ip (.199) from the server successfully, but not from the www. Any ideas why this is the case? I want to make sure that my second IP is also accessible from the web. What am I missing in this configuration?
Many thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
I am running docker but at this point, everything I stated here is in the host machine. So Docker is not yet involved...

`ip -br link` gives me:

```
$ ip -br link
lo               UNKNOWN        00:00:00:00:00:00 <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> 
enp9s0           UP             a8:a1:22:1f:22:82 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
docker0          DOWN           02:42:f8:c5:ee:a9 <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>
br-ef57c188e0de  DOWN           02:42:dc:79:c6:f6 <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>
```

and...

```
$ ip -4 -br address
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 
enp9s0           UP             50.50.50.201/32 50.50.50.199/32 
docker0          DOWN           172.17.0.1/16
br-ef57c188e0de  DOWN           172.18.0.1/16
```

and...

```
$ ip route
default via 50.50.50.193 dev enp9s0 proto static onlink 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-ef57c188e0de proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown
```

and...

```
$ ip rule
0:  from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

and...

```
$ ip neigh
172.18.0.2 dev br-ef57c188e0de  FAILED
50.50.50.193 dev enp9s0 lladdr a8:a1:22:1f:22:82 REACHABLE
fe80::1 dev enp9s0 lladdr a8:a1:22:1f:22:82 router STALE
```

and finally...

```
$ iptables-save -c
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sat May 14 17:40:11 2022
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [1021:88276]
:FORWARD DROP [233:12218]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [920:161517]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
[12631:643908] -A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
[12631:643908] -A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
[105:5500] -A FORWARD -o br-ef57c188e0de -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-ef57c188e0de -j DOCKER
[6:324] -A FORWARD -i br-ef57c188e0de ! -o br-ef57c188e0de -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-ef57c188e0de -o br-ef57c188e0de -j ACCEPT
[521962:778892991] -A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
[132612:7158451] -A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
[6:324] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-ef57c188e0de ! -o br-ef57c188e0de -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
[132612:7158451] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
[686521:790836880] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-ef57c188e0de -j DROP
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
[132618:7158775] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
[709846:791932195] -A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat May 14 17:40:11 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sat May 14 17:40:11 2022
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [585:28528]
:INPUT ACCEPT [357:16571]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [12:720]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [12:720]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
[25260:1227195] -A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
[3:252] -A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
[3:180] -A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.0/16 ! -o br-ef57c188e0de -j MASQUERADE
[64:3912] -A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
[0:0] -A DOCKER -i br-ef57c188e0de -j RETURN
[0:0] -A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat May 14 17:40:11 2022
```

In addition, I haven't set up any firewall rules yet on Hetzner side either.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: This should be working (because there's the onlink parameter allowing to have a gateway without LAN route). As it's not you should provide more information: `ip -br link; ip -4 -br address; ip route; ip rule; ip neigh`. Also just in case check firewall rules. So: `iptables-save -c` too. Note: Docker never helps when present to troubleshoot network issues. If you forgot to tell your service was behind Docker, it's time to tell it and describe it: this can matter.

Comment: I edited the question with the additional info you've asked. Thx for your time ;)

Comment: It's supposed to work. You should compare from the server side since it's easier than from remote: `ping 50.50.50.193` vs `ping -I 50.50.50.199 50.50.50.193` and `traceroute -n 8.8.8.8` vs `traceroute -s 50.50.50.199 8.8.8.8`. You could run at the same time something like `traceroute -l -n -s0 -e -p -i enp9s0 arp or icmp` and see if something looks wrong or different between both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help everyone and especially [A.B](https://serverfault.com/users/217515/a-b)

Pinging still didn't work. I read all the Hetzner docs and couldn't find any clues until I stumbled upon this post [Hetzner additional ip](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/hetzner-one-additional-ip-route-not-working.74786/). I had earlier activated the MAC address for the additional IP I've requested because I thought it would be necessary to create a macvlan in docker. I **disabled the virtual MAC address** in the Hetzner server portal and now I can ping from and to the additional IP. What I haven't figured out yet is described in another post: [assigning 32 ip address to docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72237540/assigning-32-ip-addr-to-containers-with-docker-compose-ubuntu-20-04). Any help there is more then welcome. Cheers!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).